# Linking a Google Map to MS Access

Tags: google-maps, ms-access

So I have been doing a lot of research on this topic but I am new to working with online mapping. I have an access database and I would like to portray information in a google map. I have learned how to embed a google map into an access database but I am looking for the reverse. I want to take the data from the access database export it out, send it to a website, and have a google map on the website showing the information.

Any suggestions on how to perform this action?

Comment: What kind of data? XY locations?

Comment: Yes XY Locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) install QGIS http://www.qgis.org/en/site/

2) export your access database to a csv

3) import csv to QGIS http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html

4) save resulting vector dataset as .kml http://www.igismap.com/convert-shapefile-kml-qgis/

5) import kml file to google earth http://www.google.com/earth/learn/advanced.html#tab=importing-kml-kmz-and-gps-data

For getting the kml data to display in a map viewer (on a website), you can look at the developer documentation on creating a google map widget and displaying information from Google My Maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps#whats_changing).

Adding kml data to Google My Maps (https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?hl=en) Displaying KML data on google map viewer (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/kml#overview)